# Circular references in dask with out-of-core computations

Tags: python, dask

I am writing a library that implements various out of core algorithms and have run into the issue that it is possible to build a circularly dependent computation graph by source and storing to the same memmapped object. For example

```
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da

array_shape = (8000, 8000)
chunk_shape = (100, 100)

### create the example data
adisk = np.memmap('/tmp/a.npy', dtype=np.float32, shape=array_shape)
bdisk = np.memmap('/tmp/b.npy', dtype=np.float32, shape=array_shape)

a = da.ones(mainshape, chunks=chunkshape, dtype=np.float32) 
b = 2*da.ones(mainshape, chunks=chunkshape, dtype=np.float32) 

a.store(adisk)
b.store(bdisk)
adisk.flush()
bdisk.flush()

### Begin demonstration of issue

c = da.from_array(adisk, chunks=chunkshape)
d = da.from_array(bdisk, chunks=chunkshape)

e = c@d

e.store(adisk)

# Assert fails because source data is overwritten before re-read
assert np.all(adisk[:] == adisk[0,0])
```

My testing suggests that if the data is too large to cache in memory the dask will complete the operation but the behaviour is undefined as source data can be overwritten by result data before it is reused for other parts of the computation.  Thus the above code ceases to produce correct results above a certain (machine dependent) matrix size.

Does dask provide any methods to help detect and mitigate such circular dependencies?

I have looked into potential solutions and I am currently thinking that a plugin function could be useful here to check that the target of a store operation is not the same as any source further back in the chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a solution for my purposes that can be used to check that there are no circular dependencies.  In my case because of the code structure I can easily guard the potential issues with e.g `assert no_circular_dependencies(e, adisk)` but in general this would be tricky to achieve without Monkeypatching Dask.

Because each dask array keeps a list of all tasks in the taskgraph it is straightforward to check the graph to find original data sources and ensure that they are not the same as the destination array.

```
def get_true_base(ndarr):
    if not isinstance(ndarr, np.ndarray):
        raise TypeError("expected numpy array")
    base = ndarr
    while True:
        try:
            base = base.base
        except AttributeError:
            break
    return base

def get_memmap_bases(dsk):
    # better to build a set of names and then grab arrays later
    nameset = set()
    for name, task in dsk.items():
        if isinstance(task[0], np.memmap):
            nameset.add(name)

    bases = [get_true_base(dsk[name][0]) for name in nameset]
    return bases 

def no_circular_dependency(dask_arr, target):
    if get_true_base(target) in get_memmap_bases(dask_arr.dask):
        return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that dask.array tokenizes memmapped objects by filename and last modification time.  Cases like this where it is yet to be written to seem like a fail case.

I would expect this to fail somewhere in the task optimization phase.

Short term I recommend explicitly providing a `name=` keyword to the `da.from_array` function to provide your own unique ID.

Comment: But that's the thing.  In the program above dask completes the operations without complaint, even explicitly specifying unique names for all my dask arrays.  The problem is that it seems to have no guard against using the same array as both source and sink.

Comment: Please also see that the data is not "yet to be written". It is explicitly written and flushed so consider the from array steps as if they are the start of the program we care about.  The issue is the need to read source blocks which have already been overwritten by result blocks.

Comment: In principle someone might want to read from and write to the same array.  I'm not sure that Dask should err here.  Even if it should it's not clear that we could easily.

Comment: I agree completely that disallowing operations to read and write from the same object is not a solution. However, I think this does highlight a potential pitfall with `store`: the results of the example are dependent upon the order in which dask chooses to do the operations.  I would suggest that this is definitely not a desirable behaviour and something that dask should be able to detect and warn about.  In most cases this problem can be avoided by using `compute` which explicitly creates a new array for the result even if it then replaces a source array.